# List of SVN changes in working copy in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I make Team -> Commit I can see list of all changes I've done in my working copy.

Can I see that list same way as I can see files in Project Explorer (as some kind of filter maybe)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right click on the project -> Team -> Synchronize...
It will take you to synchronize perspective with outgoing and incoming changes.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the project -> Team -> Show History.

What you get from the Commit dialog is probably not a list of changes in the repository, but a list of commit comments you wrote previously, hence having only **your** last commit comments.

At least that is the behaviour of the Subclipse plugin.